# How to convert an Oracle DB 11.2.0.3 to a 12cR2 PDB using Oracle Sqldeveloper?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, oracle11gr2

How to convert an Oracle DB 11.2.0.3  to a 12cR2 PDB using Oracle Sqldeveloper?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong on this site, and is too broad and vague to migrate to DBA.SE.

Comment: Have you tried the steps in the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/upgrade-scenarios-non-cdb-oracle-databases.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that. SQL Developer does quite a lot of things, but I doubt that it is capable of upgrading a database version.

This is the Database Upgrade Guide (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/toc.htm). Recommended method is Database Upgrade Assistant (DBUA), although you can do it manually. The question is: are you capable of doing it? I'm not implying that you're stupid, God forbid, but you might not have enough knowledge and/or experience. Perhaps you should discuss it with a proper DBA.

Comment: Mike has a great blog post on how to do this as well https://mikedietrichde.com/2015/01/29/upgrade-to-12c-and-plugin-one-fast-way-to-move-into-the-world-of-oracle-multitenant/

Comment: Right; Mike's step D is "hutdown" :)  @thatjeffsmith, I know you are a SQL Developer expert, so - just wondering, can it be done with that tool?

Comment: no, which is why i marked your answer as correct :) We have no, take this instance and turn it into a PDB over there feature.

Comment: OK, thank you. (Now writing some more letters because comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)